# Why is instance member static in singleton class?

Tags: c#, singleton

This is a singleton class

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    static Singleton instance=null;
    static readonly object padlock = new object();

    Singleton()
    {
    }

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (padlock)
            {
                if (instance==null)
                {
                    instance = new Singleton();
                }
                return instance;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my question is `static Singleton instance=null;`  why this is static?

Comment: This doesn't particularly look like a (current) threadsafe, performant singleton pattern in .Net. (I realize it's the MSDN P&P code for the pattern). See @JonSkeet 's http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Comment: Because if it wasn't, it wouldn't be a singleton.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 'instance' field holds the reference of the one and only instance.

It is stored in a static variable because its scope has to be the class itself and not a particular instance.

Answer (score 5):

Because you are referencing the variable inside a static Property (Instance) and you can't reference instance variables inside static methods or properties.

The idea of having a Singleton is to only have one and only one instance at all times running.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of Singleton is to have only one instance of that object[1]. By making a sealed class with a private static instance which is automatically instantiated on first access, you provide its necessary trait of only creating one copy of the actual object that is then accessed by the Singleton.Instance property elsewhere in the system.

[1] within any AppDomain, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Because it if would not be static, it would be a singleton only in name. And i could create thousands of instance of it.

Comment: With a private constructor you can't create thousands of instances.

Comment: With ap rivate constructor you can not create a SINGLE instance, which makes the singleton a noinstanceton.

Answer (score 0):

Because you only want one (static) instance ever in the program

Answer (score 0):

It is static so every instance of the Singleton type will use the same variable, hence the "singleton" pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Succinctly, Singleton is a design pattern used to ensure that only one instance of something is ever created within a given scope.

This pattern is accomplished by a few main concepts:

1. creating a static instance of some object
2. creating a private constructor
3. disallowing the class to be extended by another (sealed)
4. providing a static method that returns an instance of the static
   object

The example code you provided is a textbook example of the Singleton pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I think because you used:

```
public static Singleton Instance()
```

That function is static, so your instance variable need to be static too.